# Magento 2 Checkout page after payment redirect auto redirect to step 1

Tags: magento2, magento24

I am currently using Magento 2.4.6. I have encountered an issue with the checkout page. Whenever there is an error in the payment method, it displays an error message, but after 2-3 seconds, it redirects back to step 1.

I wanted to check if anyone else is facing the same problem and if there is any known solution for this issue.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

i debug the issue and i found the code in below file
pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Checkout\js\model\place-order.js

that is only available in magento246,
they redirect cusomer to step 1 after 3 second